# casting and deserialization

Tags: c#, xml

I am having a problem with deserialization. Imagine we are creating a drawing application which allows to draw lines. We have a class which is in charge with drawing methods for a line so let's call it *clsLine*.

Now, each line can have N connections with other lines at its starting and ending. So far everything ok. Now, I need to store the drawing in xml file so we go with serialization. The problem is when I open the xml file to deserialize the drawing back to the object it used to be we are getting an exception error.

The fact is that we are using a list for each line to add each connected line or line segment on its ends.

Updated:

```
public class clsLine : ShapeBase
{
    //has all the properties and methods that should be applied to a line
    //e.g. length, angle, and etc.
    Connections endConnections = new Connections();
    Connections startConnections = new Connections();

}


public class Connection
{
    clsLine segment;
    int handle;

    public clsLine Segment
    {
        get { return segment; }
        set { segment = value; }
    }

    public int Handle
    {
        get { return handle; }
        set { handle = value; }
    }
}



public class Connections : List<Connection>
{
   public bool Contains(ShapeBase instance)
   {
        foreach (Connection con in this)
        {
            if (instance.Equals(con.Segment))
               return true;
        }
        return false;
   }
}
```

Now, during deserialzation we get an exception as:

*'Add value to collection of type 'OurProjectNameSpace.Connections' threw an exception.'*

My colleague explains that this is due to casting from  "Connection" to "Connections" which makes sense. Keep in mind that Connections is an array or list of Connection type.

Can we get some heads up here?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post what the exception actually is? You might have to look at an InnerException for that.

Comment: It is {"The value \"namespace.Connections\" is not of type \"namespace.Connection\" and cannot be used in this generic collection.\r\nParameter name: value"}   Thank you

Comment: You need to share more source code for reference. What is `clsLine`, `this`, `Connection`, etc.?

Comment: Is con.Segment a clsLine type?  If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: I will post that portion of code to make it more clear.

Comment: How are you doing your serialization/deserialization? Can you show a sample of the Xml output?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create your own serialization and deserialization routines for these types.
Especially when using collection types and derivatives thereof, you might want to control the (de)serialization process.

Information of how-to do custom serialization can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.80).aspx

When using XML serialization you might also want to implement `IXmlSerializable`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.80).aspx